# how do i add a library to xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin

This sounds like a very simple question, but please don't have a go at me. I have tried searching. perhaps i'm just using the wrong terminology.

I'm not new to visual studio, i've been using it ever since version 6... but i am relatively new to .net.

I have written apps which used nuget libraries. this is a piece of cake. but now I want to use this library:
https://github.com/anotherlab/UsbSerialForAndroid

how on earth do i add this? There's no nuget?

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: in the Solution Explorer, use "Add Reference"

Comment: but what do i add? The github link i put in the description is just a xamarin project consisting of a sample app and a library. There's no dll's, so i don't know what to add.

Comment: either add the project to your solution, or build the project separately and add the dll

Comment: Download the source code. Copy folder "UsbSerialForAndroid" into your solution's folder. Open your current solution in VS. In Solution Explorer, rt-click on Solution node, Add / Existing Project. Select UsbSerialForAndroid/UsbSerialForAndroid.csproj. In Solution Explorer, rt-click on your main project, Add / Project Reference.